# Overloading across inheritance boundaries in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, clr

After reading this **[article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)**  &  that **[article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/brittle+base+classes/)**   - I got confused.

It says :

> If there are two methods at different levels of the hierarchy, the
>   "deeper" one will be chosen first, even if it isn't a "better function
>   member" for the call.

Also -

> It turns out that if you override a base class method in a child
>   class, that doesn't count as declaring it.

Now let's go back to my question :

### Case 1

```
    public class Base
     {
           public virtual void  Foo(int x)  { "1".Dump();}
     }

    public class Child : Base
     {
          public void Foo(object x) { "3".Dump();}  
          public override void  Foo(int x)  { "2".Dump();}
     }


void Main()
{
    Child c = new Child();
    c.Foo(10); //emits 3
}
```

OK.According to the article

> "deeper" one will be chosen first, even if it isn't a "better function. and it doesn't count the override...

So it is right  and the program emits "3". ( `Foo(object x)` is executed)

Let's change line **order of 1 line** :

### Case 2

```
          public class Base
         {
                 public virtual void  Foo(int x)  { "1".Dump();}
                 public void Foo(object x) { "3".Dump();} //<line being moved here
         }

        public class Child : Base
         {
              public override void  Foo(int x)  { "2".Dump();}
         }


    void Main()
    {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.Foo(10); //emits 2 !!!!
    }
```

Now it emits "2".

Now lets change all *int to object* and all *object to int* :

### Case 3

```
      public class Base
    {
      public virtual void  Foo(object x)  { "1".Dump();}
      public void Foo(int x) { "3".Dump();} 
    }

    public class Child : Base
    {
         public override void  Foo(object x)  { "2".Dump();}
    }


void Main()
{
    Child c = new Child();
    c.Foo(1); //emits "3"
}
```

**Questions** :

---

**Question#1 :** in case 2 , `Child`  inherited the  `Foo(object x)` from its father  AND he also overrides a method.

**but** didnt we just say that  :

> It turns out that if you override a base class method in a child
>   class, that doesn't count as declaring it

???

in fact, we didnt also declared the inherited function ... so **what is the rule** here in this situation ?

---

**Question#2 :** in case 3 , `Child`  inherited the  `Foo(int x)` from its father  AND he also overrides a method.

but now , he chooses its father function....

it seems like `override` is winning only if it has exact match.

again , **what is the rule** here in this situation ?

---

Comment: I hope this is just out of curiosity.  IMO if the behavior of your code is dependent on confusing corner cases of the language spec, it's poorly designed.

Comment: @TimS. of course.... curiosity makes me understand better....

Comment: Overload resolution selects the method slot, then overrides are considered to arrive at the most derived applicable subclass. The virtual base method is selected in case 2 (Child's override doesn't count as a declaration); then, since it is overridden, the version in Child is actually invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [member lookup process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691331%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of a name N in a type T (in your case member `Foo` in type `Child`):

First, the set of all accessible (Section 3.5) members named N declared in T and the base types (Section 7.3.1) of T is constructed:

```
virtual void Foo(int x) // Base
void Foo(object x) // Base
override void Foo(int x) // Child
```

Declarations that include an override modifier are excluded from the set.

```
virtual void Foo(int x) // Base
void Foo(object x) // Base
```

Argument has an integer type. So, best choice here is (argument type matches parameter type)

```
virtual void Foo(int x) // Base
```

And this method called. But it is virtual method. And its invoked due to [virtual method invocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) mechanism:

> For every virtual method declared in or inherited by a class, there
>   exists a most derived implementation of the method with respect to
>   that class. The most derived implementation of a virtual method M with
>   respect to a class R is determined as follows:
>
> - If R contains the introducing virtual declaration of M, then this is the most derived implementation of M.
> - Otherwise, if R contains an override of M, then this is the most derived implementation of M.
> - Otherwise, the most derived implementation of M with respect to R is the same as the most derived implementation of M with respect to
>     the direct base class of R.

And what is most derived implementation of `virtual void Foo(int x)` method with respect to a class `Child`? Yes, it is

```
override void Foo(int x) // Child
```

Which is invoked.
Same rules applied in your third sample. But when two options left after overridden method removing, best choice (due to argument type) is non-virtual method.

Comment: so how case 1 is explained by your answer?

Comment: In first case Child's method does not have `override` modifier. And it is applicable according to argument list `Foo(object x)`. Thus all base class methods are removed from set. You can find explanation on method invocations description http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691356(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Child's method **does** have override modifier.

Comment: Child has two methods. One with `override` modifier is removed from set. We have second Child's method `public void Foo(object x)` without `override` modifier. This method applicable, thus all base class methods are removed from set.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things happening:

1. When selecting the method to invoke, the compiler will obey the rules as per the linked articles - ie. a deeper method will be chosen before a shallower one even if the shallower one is a more specific match
2. If you call an overridden method, it will always call the overridden method (this is separate to selecting which method to call), the "only" way to call the base method is from the subclass and using base.MyMethod(..)

So basically the lookup rules can choose the method taking an int if it's on a deeper class, but when the method gets called, if it's been overridden it will call the method taking an int on the child class.

Comment: _the "only" way to call the base method is from the subclass and using base.MyMethod_ ????? it inherit te func from its father. no base.xxx is needed here

Comment: if xxx is overridden by Child, then unless you do some fancy footwork child.xxx is always going to call the xxx method on Child, and if you want to call the xxx method defined in Parent on an instance of Child then you need to call base.xxx from Child

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just messing up your facts by reading the two articles.. It should behave like any other normal overridden function as there is no  overloading in the child class and thus there is nothing to choose from.. Lets take a simple example:

```
public class A
{
  public virtual void Foo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("A.Foo() called");
  }
}

public class B: A
{
  public override void Foo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("B.Foo() called");
  }
}

void Main()
{
new B().Foo();
}
```

What is the expected output? Obviously without thinking twice anyones gonna say B.Foo() called. Well in your case the very same thing is happening. It doesnt matter that the base class has a better overloaded method, the child class just wins it.. Dont over-complicate things..

About case 3, I am not totally sure about this one, but what happens here is that the compiler tries the implicit conversion to object and then it finds that there is a deeper method with the same signature and thus the rule

> if there are two methods at different levels of the hierarchy, the
>   "deeper" one will be chosen first, even if it isn't a "better function
>   member" for the call

and now once it goes to the base class it notices that there is a better method that can be used and hence calls that method..

P.S: The explanation above is based on the results that have been observed and might not necessarily be the exact reasons for the above seen behavior.